# Powershell - capture all non-blank lines between key words

Tags: powershell

I have a script that was put together with the community help and it works great.  I'm trying to alter it to work for my new requirements.
I have data (See below) that needs to be captured from 10K+ files.
Inside each file could be multiple iterations of the data I need to capture.  The script I'm using captured only the file name and not the data I need.  Can someone see where I'm off (Code wise) and offer another option.

Here is my Raw Data.  There could be four or five places in a text member with this data and I need to capture it all.
The words in Bold (Select and From) are the words I'm keying on.  I need to capture those lines as well as all the lines between them.

```
    SELECT   FIL_ID_NUM,                                             00481002
             LAU_CRE_DTS,                                            00482002
             LAU_CD,                                                 00483002
             LAU_EFF_DT,                                             00484002
             LAU_EFF_TIM,                                            00485002
             LAU_EXP_DT,                                             00486002
             LAU_EXP_TIM,                                            00487002
             LAU_SERV_REAS1_CD,                                      00488002
             LAU_SERV_REAS2_CD,                                      00489002
             LAU_SERV_REAS3_CD,                                      00489102
             LAU_CARE_IND,                                           00489202
             SEG_UPDT_LOCK_NUM,                                      00489302
             LAU_AGRMT_PER_NAM,                                      00489402
             LAU_AGRMT_DSGT_NAM,                                     00489502
             LAU_AGRMT_DIR_TXT,                                      00489602
             LAU_TERMS_TXT                                           00489702
                                                                     00520002
        FROM TLEGAL
```

Here is my script....

```
# create a List object to collect the 'flowerbox' strings in
$Flowerbox = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$treat = $false

# get a list of the .pl1m files and loop through. Collect all output in variable $result
$CBLFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\src' -Filter '*.pl1m' -File -Recurse
$result = foreach ($CBLFile in $CBLFileList) {
    Write-Host "Processing ... $($CBLFile.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green
    
    $Flowerbox.Clear()  # empty the list for the next run
    $treat = $false
    switch -Regex -File $CBLFile.FullName {
        'SELECT' { 
        Write-Host "Found Select" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
            # start collecting lines from here    
            $treat = $true
        }
        'FROM ' {
        Write-Host "Found From" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
           if ($treat) {
           
            # stop colecting Flowerbox lines and output what we already have
            # output an object with the two properties you need
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Program     = $CBLFile.Name  # or $CBLFile.FullName
                Description = $Flowerbox -join [environment]::NewLine
            }
            }
            $Flowerbox.Clear()  # empty the list for the next run
            $treat = $false
        }
        default {
                # Add captures data here
                if ($treat -and ($_ -match '/[^\s\\]/')) { 
                $Flowerbox.Add($Matches[1])
            }
        }
    }
}

# now you have everything in an array of PSObjects so you can save that as Csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\src\SQL_Desc.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Basically, you're looking to capture __all__ appearances of those fragments starting on `SELECT` and ending on `FROM TLEGAL` __from 10k files__, is that right?

Comment: Correct!  Starting on select and ending with from, including the lines with the key words on them.

Comment: Do these files fit in memory? What's their size?

Comment: I have run this script altered on the same folder with no memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script needs only a few tweaks:

- Add the *full line*, reflected in `$_`, to your `$Flowerbox` list
- Also do so in the `'SELECT'` and `'FROM '` branches.

```
# ...
$Flowerbox.Clear()  # empty the list for the next run
$treat = $false
switch -Regex -CaseSensitive -File $CBLFile.FullName {
  '^\s*SELECT\s' { 
    Write-Host "Found Select" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
    # start collecting lines from here    
    $treat = $true
    $Flowerbox.Add($_) # Add this line to the list.
    continue # So that the FROM branch needn't also be checked.
  }
  '^\s*FROM\s' {
    Write-Host "Found From" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
    if ($treat) {
      $Flowerbox.Add($_)  # Add this line to the list.
      # stop collecting Flowerbox lines and output what we already have
      # output an object with the two properties you need
      [PsCustomObject]@{
        Program     = $CBLFile.Name  # or $CBLFile.FullName
        Description = $Flowerbox -join [environment]::NewLine
      }
      $Flowerbox.Clear()  # empty the list for the next run
      $treat = $false
    }
  }
  default {
    # When inside a block of interest, add all non-blank lines.
    if ($treat -and $_ -match '\S') {
      $Flowerbox.Add($_)  # Add this line to the list.
    }
  }
}
# ...
```

Note that, in the interest of minimizing the risk of false positives:

- `-CaseSensitive` was added to the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement for case-sensitive matching.
- The regexes were made more robust to prevent accidental substring matching and to tolerate whitespace variations (spaces vs. tabs).

Also, to exclude blank (empty and all-whitespace) lines, condition `-match '\S'` was added to the `default` branch.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this function to find all those files that contain those fragments starting on `SELECT` and ending on `FROM`, the function would output objects with the **captured fragment** (`Value`), `Index`, `Path` and `Length`. The *regex* is likely to be improved, but this worked for me with some test files.

**NOTE**: this answer **requires** that the files fit in memory, as the functions reads the files as a **whole string**.

```
using namespace System.IO

function Find-String {
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [FileInfo]$Path,
    [parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
    [regex]$Pattern,
    [switch]$AllMatches
)

    process {
        $content = [File]::ReadAllText($Path)
        $match = if($AllMatches.IsPresent) {
            $Pattern.Matches($content)
        }
        else {
            $Pattern.Match($content)
        }

        if($match.Success -notcontains $true) {
            return
        }

        foreach($m in $match) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Path   = $path.FullName
                Value  = $m.Value
                Index  = $m.Index
                Length = $m.Length
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\src' -Filter '*.pl1m' -Recurse |
    Find-String -Pattern '(?msi)SELECT.*?FROM.*?$' -AllMatches |
    Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output with one particular file looks like this:

```
Path   : /home/user/Documents/test.txt
Value  : SELECT  FIL_ID_NUM,             00481002
         ...
         ...
         ...
         FROM SOMETABLE
Index  : 11
Length : 449

Path   : /home/user/Documents/test.txt
Value  : SELECT  FIL_ID_NUM,             00481002
         ...
         ...
         ...
         FROM SOMEOTHERTABLE
Index  : 501
Length : 522
```

Answer (score 1):

I love Santiago Squarzon's approach, but his code doesn't seem to remove blank lines.  This code is a little bit of a hybrid of everyone else's code.  I learned a lot about switch by doing this, amazing what you can get switch to do once you get your head wrapped around what it is doing.

```
function Process-Line {
    Process {
        ($Input -Split ',' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } ) -join ', ' 
    }
}
function Process-File {
    Process {
        $Inside = $false;
        switch -Regex -File $Input.FullName {
            '^\s*$' { continue }
            '(?i)^\s*SELECT\s.*$' { $Inside = $true }
            '^.+$'                { if($Inside) { $Matches[0] | Process-Line } }
            '(?i)^\s*from\s.*$'   { $Inside = $false }
            default { continue }
        }
    }
}
$Result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Sync\Projects\ps1\Crypto' -Filter '*.pl1m' -Recurse | Process-File
$Result | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Sync\Projects\ps1\Crypto\SQL_Desc.csv'
```

Taking your data exactly as is, it produced this, which I'm nearly 100% sure isn't exactly what you want.  If you give some more details on the exact layout of the CSV, and if you are sure the source data is missing commas, I think we can figure a way to beat it into shape.  But we need to get it into a uniform pattern before packaging it in a PSCustomObject and piping it to Export-CSV.

```
SELECT   FIL_ID_NUM, 00481002
LAU_CRE_DTS, 00482002
LAU_CD, 00483002
LAU_EFF_DT, 00484002
LAU_EFF_TIM, 00485002
LAU_EXP_DT, 00486002
LAU_EXP_TIM, 00487002
LAU_SERV_REAS1_CD, 00488002
LAU_SERV_REAS2_CD, 00489002
LAU_SERV_REAS3_CD, 00489102
LAU_CARE_IND, 00489202
SEG_UPDT_LOCK_NUM, 00489302
LAU_AGRMT_PER_NAM, 00489402
LAU_AGRMT_DSGT_NAM, 00489502
LAU_AGRMT_DIR_TXT, 00489602
LAU_TERMS_TXT                                           00489702
00520002
FROM TLEGAL
```

Also, do you want:

1. A header line in the csv file? And if so, what column headers do you want?
2. Are there really numbers, such as the last number (00520002), on a line by themselves?

3. Do you want the "SELECT" and "FROM TLEGAL" to appear?  They don't fit well in the CSV format.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code!!
Hi, I will try your solution right now and report back.  Yes that output does look close to what I'm looking for and yes there are blank lines with numerics at the end.  I can deal with that if I have to.  I don't really need headers for anything other than the primary ones at the top of the file.  I just need the file name in one cell and the other data in the adjoining cell in the next column.
I need the lines of the search words also.  I cannot hit for TLEGAL as that will change.  I can only hit for SELECT and FROM.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to understanding the end goal, but it would help if you gave an example of what your original data would look like after being processed - with the line that has the file name included.   Also, it probably wouldn't take a lot of work to either filter out the lines with only numerics, or given them a dummy left column such as "Line745, 00489702"

Comment: If you liked my function you can try the original one here https://gist.github.com/santysq/dc3c302be515e029cf8c01ca58a60b73, it has another parameter for _Context_ (characters before and characters after the matched pattern) :)

Comment: Thank you - I think I am good to go.  I was able to alter the script above to get what I need.  Once I have it cleaned - I will post the final.
Thank you to everyone for your help!!!!!

-Ron